# Facebook - Refer a friend functionality

Tags: facebook

I need to create some functionality on a clients website which lists the users friends and allows them to send a link to their inbox.

So far, I have it listing the users friends using `fb.api` functionality, but from what I can see, there is no way to send the users friend a message (not post to their wall, this needs to go into their inbox.)

edit: The user would log in first.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've tried looking at [`fb.ui`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) but I can't seem to find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is (or should be) impossible. I wouldn't like it at all if a third party could send me messages because **one of my friends allowed it**. I guess that would be my last day on Facebook.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The user would log in using connect first, and the message would come from the user. It's basically a referral scheme.

Comment: It's not your good intentions that I questioned. But this feature could be used to promote anything including Viagra, pr0n, etc :) Imagine: a girl with a nice picture adds you (of course you accept), and a week or two later you get such an "invitation" from her.

Comment: Sure I understand that, I wouldn't want that either! What I'm trying to say is, all I want to do is show a UI window where the user can send their friend a message, from themselves. Kind of like on that MGM website but perhaps with a pre-populated recipient field.

Comment: Well, that MGM page is on FB and I think it is officially approved an reviewed by the staff. If I understand correctly, you are building a web app and not a Facebook page and I don't think such functionality is available for you. But I think it can be done with the Google Contacts API.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the fbml fb:request-form doc's. It looks to me like this is what MGM is using. This allows a user to invite friends, and I think it's as close as you can get to what you are truly after.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form

Comment: I think that now (in 2013) this fbml stuff is deprecated. I believe this is the replacement: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/